# Why am I getting an array out of range error in this code?

Tags: arrays, mql4

## Initial Problem

I am trying to plot the RSI of an indicator, "xxx.mq4", as follows:

```
#property indicator_buffers 1
#property indicator_color1 Red
#property indicator_width1 2

//---- buffers
double ExtMapBufferCustomIndicator[];
double ExtMapBufferRSICustomIndicator[];
int i;
string s="xxx";

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function                         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int init()
  {
//---- indicators
   SetIndexStyle(0,DRAW_LINE);
   SetIndexBuffer(0,ExtMapBufferRSICustomIndicator);
   SetIndexLabel(0,"RSICustomIndicator");
   
   IndicatorShortName("RSI of xxx: RSICustomIndicator");
//----
   return(0);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator deinitialization function                       |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int deinit()
  {
//----
   return(0);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator iteration function                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int start()
  {
   int counted_bars=IndicatorCounted();
   if(counted_bars < 0)  return(-1);
   if(counted_bars>0) counted_bars--;
   int limit=Bars-counted_bars;
   if(counted_bars==0) limit-=15;
//   printf(limit);
//---- main loop
   for(i=0; i<limit; i++)
     {
      ExtMapBufferCustomIndicator[i]= iCustom(NULL,0,s,20,40,0,0);
     }
   for(i=0; i<limit; i++)
     {
      ExtMapBufferRSICustomIndicator[i]=iRSIOnArray(ExtMapBufferCustomIndicator,0,14,0);
     }
//---- done
   return(0);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

but I get the following error on running: "RSIxxx [instrument],H1: array out of range in 'RSIxxx.mq4' (55,26)

The reference is to this line:

```
ExtMapBufferCustomIndicator[i]= iCustom(NULL,0,s,20,40,0,0);
```

NB The original indicator works fine

## Persistance of error even by simplifying code!

Even by removing the reference to the external code and replacing it with a recalculation of the original indicator the same problem occurs

All suggestions gratefully received!

## Edit 2019-02-09

In order to clarify, and in answer to the initial two responders, the same error occurs with this code:

```
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//|                                  Copyright © 2019, Andy Thompson |
//|                                   mailto:andydoc1@googlemail.com |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
#property copyright "Copyright © 2019, Andy Thompson"
#property link      "mailto:andydoc1@googlemail.com"
#property strict
#property indicator_separate_window
#property indicator_buffers 1
#property indicator_color1 Red
#property indicator_width1 2

//---- buffers
double intCalcxxx[];
double ExtMapBufferRSIxxx[];
int i;

//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator initialization function                         |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int init()
  {
//---- indicators
   SetIndexStyle(0,DRAW_LINE);
   SetIndexBuffer(0,ExtMapBufferRSIxxx);
   SetIndexLabel(0,"RSIxxx");
   ArraySetAsSeries(intCalcxxx,true);
   IndicatorShortName("RSI of xxx: RSIxxx");
//----
   return(0);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator deinitialization function                       |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int deinit()
  {
//----
   return(0);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
//| Custom indicator iteration function                              |
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
int start()
  {
   int counted_bars=IndicatorCounted();
   if(counted_bars < 0)  return(-1);
   if(counted_bars>0) counted_bars--;
   int limit=Bars-counted_bars;
   if(counted_bars==0) limit-=15;
//   printf(limit);
//---- main loop
   for(i=0; i<1000; i++)
     {
     Print(i,", ",limit);
      intCalcxxx[i]=(34.38805726*MathPow(iClose("EURUSD",0,i),0.3155)*MathPow(iClose("EURJPY",0,i),0.1891)*MathPow(iClose("EURGBP",0,i),0.3056)*MathPow(iClose("EURSEK",0,i),0.0785)*MathPow(iClose("EURCHF",0,i),0.1113))/(50.14348112*MathPow(iClose("EURUSD",0,i),-0.576)*MathPow(iClose("USDJPY",0,i),0.136)*MathPow(iClose("GBPUSD",0,i),-0.119)*MathPow(iClose("USDCAD",0,i),0.091)*MathPow(iClose("USDSEK",0,i),0.042)*MathPow(iClose("USDCHF",0,i),0.036));
     }
   for(i=0; i<1000; i++)
     {
      ExtMapBufferRSIxxx[i]=iRSIOnArray(intCalcxxx,0,14,0);
     }
//---- done
   return(0);
  }
//+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and the code compiles in MetaEditor in strict mode with no warnings or errors which would also address the point made by [nicholishen](https://www.stackoverflow.com/users/7526786/nicholishen) I believe

Comment: You've only declared one buffer but you're trying to use two buffers in your code.

Comment: lol - there are two buffers:
```
double ExtMapBufferCustomIndicator[];
double ExtMapBufferRSICustomIndicator[];
```

Comment: error message is straight forward: it happens in RSIxxx.mq4 (custom indicator) ..on the H1 time frame...I "guess" connected to the "custom parameters" (`20, 40`)...

Comment: no because when i replace the call to the external indicator with the recalculation of it, the error continues, ...as I explained at the end

Comment: No. You have declared only one buffer and two dynamic arrays. You have to explicitly map the array to a buffer. You have failed to do so.

Comment: No. I only want to draw the one line and the point is moot, as explained in the answer to the second respondent and in the original question: the same error occurs in the same place when I strip out the reference to the external custom indicator and recalculate it within this program. That other dynamic array is used in the first version simply to store the values of the external custom indicator, and in the second to store the internal calculation of the same values.

Comment: The point is not moot. You want to know why you code doesn't work don't you? You need to explicitly set the correct number of buffers in the `#property` (you have one not two) and you need to map the indicator buffers using the `SetIndexBuffer` function. Additionally, you need to specify the use-case for the buffer. Please read the docs... https://www.mql5.com/en/docs/constants/indicatorconstants/customindicatorproperties

Comment: Also, I'm not sure where you are learning MQL, but the event handling functions you're using have been deprecated for many years now. You should only be using the current MQL event handlers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you have to initialize your array, since as is, it has the size 0... which leads to "array out of range" (already at `i == 0`). Solution:

```
double intCalcxxx[1000];
```

..but then there are still problems (indicator calculates constant value), but at least no runtime exceptions!

Comment: Thank you - I overlooked this when I stopped setting it as an index buffer. Now to find out why it is returning a constant!